# How to send payload greater than 25MB to Jenkins from GitHub Web-Hooks

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks, payload, continuous-delivery

I had just started working with Jenkins for continuous integration, while going through docs of GitHub regarding web-hooks I came to know that payload is limited to 25MB. If the size exceeds the said limit than payload will be ignored. You can find the Git-Hub Documentation on payload size limit here(https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)

I have a very big project and we commit the code once every week post review and sometimes the aggregate size of the files might be greater than 25MB. Can someone help me on how to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might be some confusion about the sizes involved here.  The limit of 25 MB is not a limit of the size of the files pushed, but of the webhook payload size.  In other words, the limitation is on the size of the body of the webhook that GitHub sends you, not how much data you send to GitHub.

However, there isn't a way to raise this: it's a hard limit.  Large payloads are more likely to fail and need to be retried, and they take up more space when they're queued to be sent.

If you need to be sure that your webhook payloads are received, then you need to be sure that they'll be small.  How you do that depends on which types of events you're listening for.  Note that the `push` event lists at most 20 commits, no matter how many were pushed, so it's probably fine as it is by default.

If you're concerned that your large pushes will trigger a large webhook payload, you could try switching to a pull request-based workflow where smaller sets of commits are merged at once.